# Can't upload images php xampp on mac

Tags: php, macos

I can't upload image in folder, I'm using xampp on mac

```
<?php
    include("../../function/connection.php");   
    include("../../function/helper.php");   


    $nama_barang = $_POST['nama_barang'];
    $kategori_id = $_POST['kategori_id'];
    $spesifikasi = $_POST['spesifikasi'];    
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $button = $_POST['button'];
    $harga = $_POST['harga'];
    $stok = $_POST['stok'];

    $nama_file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../images/barang/" .$nama_file);

    if($button == "Add"){
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO barang (nama_barang, kategori_id, spesifikasi, gambar, harga, stok, status) VALUES ('$nama_barang', '$kategori_id', '$spesifikasi', '$nama_file', '$harga', '$stok', '$status')");

?>
```

this tag html form.

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL."module/barang/action.php?barang_id=$barang_id"; ?>" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Kategori</label>
        <span>
            <select name="kategori_id">
            <?php
                $queryKategori = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT kategori_id, kategori FROM kategori WHERE status='on' ORDER BY kategori ASC");
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryKategori)) {
                    if ($kategori_id == $row['kategori_id']) {
                        echo "<option value='$row[kategori_id]' selected='true'>$row[kategori]</option>";
                    }
                    echo "<option value='$row[kategori_id]'>$row[kategori]</option>";
                }
            ?>          
            </select>
        </span>
    </div> 

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Nama Barang</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="nama_barang" value="<?php echo $nama_barang; ?>" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Spesifikasi</label>
        <span>
            <textarea name="spesifikasi"><?php echo "$spesifikasi";?></textarea>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Stock</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="stok" value="<?php echo $stok; ?>" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Harga</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="harga" value="<?php echo $harga; ?>" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Gambar Produk <?php echo $keterangan_gambar;?></label>
        <span>
            <input type="file" name="file"/><?php echo $gambar;?>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="element-form">
        <label>Status</label>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="on" <?php if($status == "on"){ echo "checked='true'"; } ?> /> On
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="off" <?php if($status == "off"){ echo "checked='true'"; } ?> /> Off
        </span>
    </div>  

    <div class="element-form-add">
        <span><input type="submit" name="button" value="<?php echo $button; ?>" /></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: and how is it not working?

Comment: Can you add the html form that you are using and explain please what seems to be the error/problem with the upload?

Comment: error  cant upload file images but insert data its working, and this tag html form i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set try catch for exception checking in move upload file exception

> Here is sample code about try-catch

```
try {
//throw exception if can't move the file
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../images/barang/" .$nama_file)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not move file');
}

//do some more things with the file which may also throw an exception
//...

//ok if got here
echo "Upload Complete!";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: this tag html form: